# Why is this a power series?

Tags: calculus, power-series

Finding the power series for: $f(x) = \frac{1}{2 + x^2}$ at $c=0$

Solution after using substitution of a geometric series with $u= \frac{-1}{2}{x^2}$:

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{-x^2}{2}\right)^n$$

$$ = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac {(-1)^n x^{2n}}{2^{n+1}}$$

But this solution isn't of the form $f(x) = a_n (x - c)^n $ as x is $x^2$ even if $c = 0$.

What am I missing?

Comment: It's a power series in which the coefficients of all the odd powers happen to be $0$, so the index has been renamed. You can set $a_{2n}$ to be the coefficient of $x^{2n}$ and $a_{2n+1} = 0$ to write it in the form you prefer, but it will be harder to read.

Comment: @EthanBolker Ok thank you! When it comes to power series is it the form that makes it a power series or something else? I'm reading my textbook Calculus and early transcendentals by Jon Rogawski et al. and it isn't very clear.

Comment: In situations such as this, it may be useful to explicitly write out the first few (non-zero) terms, as: $f(x) = \frac12 - \frac14 x^2 + \frac18 x^4 - \frac{1}{16} x^6 + \cdots$ Doesn't that look like a power series?  It just happens, as Ethan Bolker says, to have odd coefficients equal to $0$.

Comment: A power series is simply a series of the form $a_0 x^0 + a_1 x^1 + a_2 x^2 + a_3 x^3 + \cdots$  It doesn't necessarily require that $a_k \not= 0$ for all $k \geq 0$ (or for *any* $k \geq 0$, for that matter).

Comment: @BrianTung Great thank you!

Comment: @user110210121 You're welcome. A power series is determined by the sequence of coefficients of the powers. How you choose to _describe_ that sequence may vary.  So for example a polynomial is a power series for which all but finitely many of the coefficients are $0$.